# Intel NUC7i7BNB with External Aorus GTX 1070

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I have an Intel NUC7i7BNB loaded with Windows 10 latest build which has Thunderbolt 3 port,

recently purchased External Aorus GTX 1070 gaming box and connected to NUC through type C Thunderbolt 3. I have also enabled primary GPU to use External Aorus from BIOS but still, the GPU is not detected even after installing the drivers from DVD.

There is no sign of Thunderbolt device connected in Device Manager.
I have tried downloading drivers from Arous official website, updating the thunderbolt drivers on the computer, reinstalling drivers from DVD.

Computers with Thunderbolt 3 ports should support External GPU, have tried on a different computer of same Model NUC7i7BNB still it is same. 
What else we can do to make this External GPU working on this Intel NUC7i7BNB

please suggest?

Comment: Maybe you need to enable thunderbolt in UEFI, just a guess...

Comment: It was already Enabled on BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the block diagram, your Thunderbolt port supports only DisplayPort and USB, the PCIe supports the integrated display processor and isn't connected through to the Thunderbolt port:

> [image]

That's just a diagram; I don't know how meaningful it is.

Comment: How does the external graphics card work on any other desktop?
I found a video online where it is set up on laptop with Thunderbolt 3  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wF2Grz8MuTM

Comment: @Ranveer: Thunderbolt *can* carry PCIe lanes.  Considering that USB-C supports alternate modes such as DP already, I don't know what purpose there would be in labeling a USB-C port with only USB and DP as "Thunderbolt".  But that's what the block diagram for your NUC shows.

Comment: Does this NUC KIT NUC8I7HVK support external GPU? I did check online but found nothing.